# How can I get a URL for a controller action?

Tags: php, url, controller, action, cakephp-2.2

I have a link that looks like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary edit" 
   href="Personas/details/<?php echo $persona['Persona']['id']; ?>" 
   data-original-title="Editar">

    <i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i>
</a>
```

As you can see I'm manually writing in the controller and action for the link. Is there some way to make this not as brittle?

Something like:

```
<a href="Url.Action("Personas", "Details", array('id', 1);" >Asdf</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use: [Html->url](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1448/url), does exactly what you want.

Comment: This doesn't work for my use case. I need to put HTML inside the link, not text.